# MySQL include empty WEEKS data as 0

Tags: mysql, sql

is there way to include empty week value from empty result ? or how i can unionn empty missing weeks

there is bit of my query

```
SELECT 
    o.user_id , WEEK(FROM_UNIXTIME(o.cdate, '%Y-%m-%d'),7) as week_number,
FROM 
    (_orders AS `o`) 
WHERE 
    o.cdate BETWEEN '1505409460' AND '1540815218'
GROUP BY 
    week_number
```

Result

```
1
2
4
6
8
```

requested result

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

Comment: You need a table (or subquery) that returns a set of integers, then left join your exist query to that list. What version of MySQL do you use? (version 8 opens up new features)

Comment: yup version 8 :)

Comment: with version 8 you could use common table expressions {with cte as (...) } to generate the needed rows. Here is quite another way to do it: [How to Create a Tally Table in MySQL](http://www.solomonson.com/content/how-create-tally-table-mysql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just an example, there are numerous ways to achieve this. The first step is to have, or generate, a set on integers. Having a table of these is very handy actually. Here I use 2 subqueries cross joined to generate 100 rows (with n = 0 to 99)

```
select
   ns.n, sq.*
from (
        select
           d1.digit + (d10.digit*10) as n
        from (
              SELECT 0 AS digit UNION ALL
              SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL  
              SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL 
              SELECT 9
              ) d1
        cross join (
              SELECT 0 AS digit UNION ALL
              SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL  
              SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL 
              SELECT 9
            ) d10
    ) ns
left join (

    your query goes here

    ) sq on ns.n = sq.week_number
where n between 1 and 52
order by n
```

Comment: Occasionally there are 53 weeks in a year.

Comment: the where clause, like the rest of the query is (as stated) an example, of course there may be more (or less) weeks or you could choose by some other measures.